# Session_Start getting called too often in chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, session

While playing around with the `global.asax.cs` file I attached some code inside of

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

and then started to notice that `Session_Start` was being called at every request when using chrome. When using firefox, this was not the case and it was only called once. What could be causing this?

To note, this is only on my dev machine. I compile and run the code, open firefox, browse to `http://localhost:63893/` and it hits `Session_Start`. While browsing in firefox it only hits `Session_Start` once.

When I open chrome and browse to `http://localhost:63893/` it hits `Session_Start`. Then I enter my login data and hit login, and it hits `Session_Start` another time, and then it hits `Session_Start` *another* time while loading the get request for the next page. I used a counter to see, and in fact 3 unique sessions were created during that time.

I know that there are some sources which state that a Session is abandoned when no value is stored in it. That would be a fine explanation here for me, but it is not the case. I disproved this from two methods.

Method 1:

```
protected void Session_End(){} /*breakpoint*/
```

Never fired, and I can confirm that the old sessions are still present.

Method 2:

Used `Session["KeepAlive"] = true;` inside of `Session_Start` to see if that would prevent `_Start` from being called but it did not. `_End` was still not called.

What is so different between the two or what have I done wrong?

Comment: The session is direct connected with a cookie on the browser. If for any reason, any call, did not find the cookie is make new session. The cookie is also connected with the host name. You may set it on one name, and try to read it from some other. The only way to actually find whats going on, is to open the tools on the chrome, see all the loaded documents and their cookie and check why they are different...

Comment: since you are using localhost with static port, so I don't think your host name is changing, however I would suggest you to debug it using fiddler (something is happening when you log in)

Comment: @highwingers - It is not just logging in when it happens, it happens on every request in chrome.

Comment: @Aristos - The host name remains the same, and so does the cookie name, when inspecting the resources tab in chrome's debugger.

Comment: maybe cookies are disabled in chrome? or some settings are off?

Comment: How have you configured sessions in your web.config?

Comment: @Alistair - Yes, they are `inProc` (which is default).

Comment: @highwingers - cookies are not disabled in chrome. I can see the sessionId cookie sitting inside of the resources tab in the debugger panel.

Comment: Load up fiddler and compare the cookies going to the server. Look at the dates  on the response and also note if the request cookie sends a value back. You could try deleting cookies, if you ever had another app locally you may see that cookie as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for all the help in comments. We actually resolved this in chat and through a link to a blog post: http://tobiefysh.blogspot.co.uk/2010/12/chrome-is-eating-my-session-varibles-or.html

It explains that `there was a 302 response when trying to get to favicon.ico`. Basically, chrome is requesting favicon.ico, it is hitting the `RegisterRoutes` method and making it into the `Session_Start` method which creates excessive Sessions.

The reason it makes it all the way to `Session_Start` is because [google chrome does not send cookies with favicon requests](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=114082). So, to all those who though it was a cookie issue: you were right.

Pretty simple fix for all the annoyance, just added this to my `RegisterRoutes` method

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("favicon.ico");
```

Now google no longer gets a session every time they want my icon.